# Identify Objects without ID or specific attributes

Tags: javascript, dom, tooltip

I'm trying to create popups from hovering above elements. The popups shall be created / loaded after hovering for the first time.

Every hover after the initial should not create a new element, but re-open the already created one.

The elements i'm hovering about **do not have an ID or a class** therefore, i cannot store these in an array for example.

```
$( ".tooltip-enabled" ).hover(
        function() {
            // Tooltip already exists? 
            // ...
            createToolTip($(this));
        }, function() {
            closeToolTip($(this));
        }
);
```

The shown code will always create a new Tooltip. Is there a way to store which object I already hovered above?

Comment: You could either store the objects you've already done popups for in an array, and check this array before making a new popup, or, if each element has unique HTML use the innerHTML.

Comment: You can have an array which holds the list of tooltips. Inside `createToolTip` check if the passed element has any ID associated. This ID is nothing but the index in the array. If ID is present then get the tooltip from the array or else create one and push it to the array and save the index (ID) to element data

Comment: This seems like a good Idea - but wouldnt work if I have duplicate tooltip - would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The shown code will always create a new Tooltip. Is there a way to
>   store which object I already hovered above?

Yes there is. You can make use of `$.fn.data` which will store a counter.

```
$(".tooltip-enabled").hover(function() {
    if ($(this).data('hovered'))
       createToolTip($(this));
    else {
       $(this).data('hovered', true); // set it here
       openToolTip($(this));
    }
},  function() { closeToolTip($(this)); });
```

Note that, to keep the code succinct, I've omitted the brackets around `if` and `else`. You need to use brackets if your code spans more than one statement.

Comment: or just `if( this.hovered ){ ... }else{ this.hovered=true; ... }`

Comment: Thanks - thats really good. I see how i will be able to check if it already has been hovered, but how can I identify which popup is to open afterwards. For example I''ll call openToolTip() if it already has been hovered isntead of createToolTIp. How will the open function be able to identify which popup is to open?